# java: illegal start of expression when entering int[]

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I cannot figure out what is the error with my input argument, the compiling errors messages are not helping much.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by cheun on 11/8/2017.
 */
public class Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex {
    static int pointer;
    static int[] arr;
    static int[] temp_arr;
    static int input;

    public static int[] myFunction(int[] arg) {
        // write the body of your function here
        for (int i = 0; i <= arg.length; i++) {
            pointer = i;
            temp_arr = arg;
            temp_arr[i] = 1; // or should put it null
            for (int j = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
                input *= temp_arr[j];
            }
            arr[pointer] = input;
        }
        return arr;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex solution = new Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex();
// line 32 FAULTY LINE BELOW
            System.out.println(myFunction([0, 1, 2, 3]));
// line 32 FAULTY LINE ABOVE    
        }

    }
```

> D:\java_workspace\InterviewQuestions\com.cake.interviews\src\Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex.java
>   Error:(32, 39) java: illegal start of expression
>   Error:(32, 40) java:
>   ')' expected Error:(32, 41) java: ';' expected
>   Error:(32, 43) java: not a statement
>   Error:(32, 44) java: ';' expected

Comment: change `[0, 1, 2, 3]` to `new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3}`

Comment: If you need more clarification and different ways to create an array in java, you may go through the following link: https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things are wrong in your program. I recommend strongly to learn the basics of the Java language. There are a lot of free resources on the Internet. Here is the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) website where you could start. And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) you can go directly to arrays in Java.

Having said that the following might be what you're trying to achieve:

```
public class Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex {

    public static int[] myFunction(int[] arg) {
        // making all variables global (=> static) doesn't make sense in this case
        int input = 1;    
        int[] temp_arr;
        int[] arr ;

        arr = new int[arg.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
            temp_arr = Arrays.copyOf(arg, arg.length);  // clone the original array; otherwise you overwrite the original one
            temp_arr[i] = 1; // or should put it null
            for (int j = 0; j < temp_arr.length; j++) {
                input *= temp_arr[j];
            }
            arr[i] = input;
            input = 1; // reset
        }
        return arr;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = myFunction(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.arr is not instantiated-> Null pointer Exception

2.If you want to input an array with numbers use this:

```
System.out.println(myFunction(new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3}));
```

or you can change definition of my Function to
myFunction(int... arg) and give parameters separated by coma

Example:

```
public class Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex {
    static int pointer;
    static int[] arr= new int[4];
    static int[] temp_arr;
    static int input;

    public static int[] myFunction(int[] arg) {
        // write the body of your function here
        for (int i = 0; i <= arg.length; i++) {
            pointer = i;
            temp_arr = arg;
            temp_arr[i] = 1; // or should put it null
            for (int j = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
                input *= temp_arr[j];
            }
            arr[pointer] = input;
        }
        return arr;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex solution = new Problem2_ProductsOfAllIntsExceptAtIndex();
// line 32 FAULTY LINE BELOW
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myFunction(new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3})));
// line 32 FAULTY LINE ABOVE    
        }

    }
```